# Enabling Windows authentication in ASP.NET Webapp

Tags: asp.net

Is there any difference between

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

vs

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```